# Populate one collection with lookup in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to populate a collection with lookup. The thing is I need to join three collections at once using mongoose in express js.
I have three collections namely, **users, skills, userskills**.

User and UserSkills are connected. Skills and UserSkills are connected. But not User and Skills.

My model is like

**users**

```
{ 
    _id: 5ec6d940b98e8f2c3cea5f22, 
    name: "test one", 
    email: "test@example.com" 
}
```

**skills**

```
{ 
    _id: 5ec786b21cea7d8c8c186a54, 
    title: "java" 
}
```

**user-skills**

```
{
    _id: 5ec7879c1cea7d8c8c186a56,
    skillId: "5ec786b21cea7d8c8c186a54",
    userId: "5ec6d940b98e8f2c3cea5f22", 
    level: "good" 
}
```

I tried

```
user = await User.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
          from: "userskills",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "userId",
          as: "userskills"
        }
      }, {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$userskills",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: "skills",
          localField: "userskills.skillId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "userskills.skill",
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id : "$_id",
          name: { $first: "$name" },
          skill: { $push: "$skills" }
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          name: 1,
          skills: {
            $filter: { input: "$skills", as: "a", cond: { $ifNull: ["$$a._id", false] } }
          } 
        }
      }]);
```

Required result:

```
{
    "users" : [
        {
            _id: "5ec6d940b98e8f2c3cea5f22"
            name: "test one",
            email: "testone@example.com",
            "skills" : [
                {
                    _id: "5ec7879c1cea7d8c8c186a56",
                    level: "good",
                    "skill" : {
                         _id: "5ec786b21cea7d8c8c186a54",
                         title: "java"
                    }
                }
           ]
        },
        {
            _id: "5ec6d940b98e8f2c3cea5f23"
            name: "test two",
            email: "testtwo@example.com",
            "skills" : [
                {
                    _id: "5ec7879c1cea7d8c8c186a57",
                    level: "good",
                    "skill" : {
                         _id: "5ec786b21cea7d8c8c186a55",
                         title: "php"
                    }
                }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

when using

```
user = await User.find().populate('Skills").exec()
```

The result is coming like

```
{
    "users" : [
        {
            _id: "5ec6d940b98e8f2c3cea5f22"
            name: "test one",
            email: "testone@example.com",
            "skills" : [
                {
                    _id: "5ec7879c1cea7d8c8c186a56",
                    level: "good",
                    skillId: "5ec786b21cea7d8c8c186a55" 
                }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is I need the skill name should also be fetched. Please help me to solve this issue. I'm writing a backend API in nodejs and mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed that second `$lookup` as part of [custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
await User.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "userskills",
            let: { user_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$user_id", "$userId" ] } } },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "skills",
                        localField: "skillId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "skill"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$skill" }
            ],
            as: "skills"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DHd9sfzMIN5)

Comment: Hi, That returned an empty array for skills

Comment: @LijomonCJohn can you compare your data with mongo playground example?

Comment: In Mongo Playground it's coming, the resut I needed, But when I run in node or mongo command line. The skills set is coming as [] (null array)

Comment: [mongo Playground] (https://mongoplayground.net/p/e9SXEgDa83b) my actaul data I need to test.

Comment: @LijomonCJohn the values in from must be the pyscical name of the collections. `from: "userskills"` is your physical collection name really `userskills`?

Comment: @LijomonCJohn double check please, maybe it is UserSkills.

Comment: @SuleymanSah the problem I found is in userskills collection the userId and skillId are not ObjectId. How do I convert that $_id to string in this code?

Comment: @LijomonCJohn better to save them as ObjectID if it is not too late.

Comment: ok...but when I fetch using passing params do alwas need to convert to string in nodejs?

Comment: Solved by changing to objectId. Thank you for helping mickl and SuleymanSah